# Facebook Graph API for iPhone Error code 1

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook Graph API for my app so as to post some default text from my UIText View.

All are getting posted. but some longer texts(I think charecter length >370),when i press "Publish" button, returns an error (Error code 1).and says try later.
All others are getting posted well.
Is there any charecter limit for the message to be posted.
or Is there any Limit for length of texts for the facebbok wall to get posted.

What could i do to get over this?
Can any one help please?
Thanks...

Comment: Is it working when calling the Facebook API directly also or only through the iPhone?

Comment: Ya its working for smaller texts.

Comment: I meant you should try the Facebook API with long ones not though the iPhone

Comment: I tried but still the same reply."Error occured,Try after some time." I used the demo app with the API,and added longtexts, textslength>400, it also give the same reply.

Comment: I suggest you try the API directly and not using the iPhone, do http request from your browser to the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all!!! Got the answer ...In the Facebook wall you can post texts with length  less than 420 characters..

Comment: There is no such restriction on facebook wall post.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect, the response this is most likely occurring is your limit is too large. Reduce the size of your limit (and therefore, the amount of information you are getting back) and it should fix this issue.